# Searching in database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid

I have a database (MS Access) connected to VB 2010. The search is a textbox and it is working, it filters what you typed in the text box but when I delete what I typed the datagrid goes blank. I want to show again in the datagrid all the records whenever I delete what I search.

Here is what I got so far.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.TextChanged
    BotikaBindingSource.Filter = "[Product name] = '" & txtsearch.Text & "'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Textbox is empty you need to call RemoveFilter for the BindingSource

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtsearch.TextChanged
    if string.IsNullOrWitheSpace(txtsearch.text) Then
        BotikaBindingSource.RemoveFilter 
    else
        BotikaBindingSource.Filter = "[Product name] = '" & txtsearch.Text  & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```